# CommonCrypto for AES 256 Apple's Library do i need to choose yes for encryption in itunes connect

Tags: ios, encryption, cryptography, app-store-connect

If we are using `FBEncryptorAES' which internally uses **commonCrypto** library do i need to check the encryption option in itunes connect ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to. From [iTC FAQ](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq):

"If your app uses, accesses, implements or incorporates industry standard encryption algorithms for purposes other than those listed as exemptions under question 2, you need to submit for an ERN authorization. Examples of standard encryption are: AES, SSL, https. This authorization requires that you submit an annual report to two U.S. Government agencies with information about your app every January."

However, then you will answer to a second question and specify purposes of encryption - if you qualify you won't have to submit for ERN authorization.